# Prove set identity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

I find it hard to prove this  identity:

Given $A,B,C$ if $A\setminus C = B\setminus C$ and $A\cap C = B\cap C$, then $A\subseteq B$.

I started by taking $x \in A$ and then $x \in A\cup \text{any set}$

but I can't find a connection from there to the given info,

can you help please?

Comment: There are two  cases:  x in C and x not in C.

Answer (score 2):

Take $a\in A$. There are two possibilities:

- $a\in C$: then $a\in A\cap C=B\cap C\subset B$.
- $a\notin C$: then $a\in A\setminus C\subset B\setminus C\subset B$.

So, in both cases, $a\in B$.

Comment: thanks, I have understood it. If I change the first condition so that C/A = C/B , can it still be proved that way?

Comment: I don't know what $C/A$ and $C/B$ are. If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, $A = B$:

$$A = (A \cap C) \cup (A \setminus C) = (B \cap C) \cup (B \setminus C) = B$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Take any  $x\in A$ and  consider the alternative:

- either $x$ also lies in $C$,
- or it doesn't,

and use the hypotheses in each case.

Answer (score 0):

$\forall x \in A$ either $x \in A\setminus C$ or $x \in A\cap C$

$x \in A\setminus C \implies x\in B\setminus C$ and $x\in B$

$x \in A\cap C \implies x\in B\cap C$ and $x\in B$

Answer (score 0):

> I find it hard to prove this identity:

Why?

$A$ is the union of $A\cap C$ and $A\smallsetminus C$.   You have been told that *each* of these sets are *equal to* sets which are themselves obviously subsets of $B$.   Therefore $A$ is the union of subsets of $B$ and thus itself a subset of $B$.

A more formal proof will use a "proof by cases" structure.

$$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{(A\cap C)=(B\cap C)\\ (A\smallsetminus C)=(B\smallsetminus C)}{\fitch{x\in A}{\fitch{x\in C}{x\in A\wedge x\in C\\~ \\ ~\\ ~\\ x\in B}\qquad\fitch{x\notin C}{x\in A\wedge x\notin C\\~\\~\\ ~\\ x\in B}\\x\in B}\\x\in A\to x\in B\\ A\subseteq B}$$

Fill in the missing steps and provide justifications.